# How to separate i18n language folders into another repo?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

So, we have a React project with +50 languages. We are using i18n with `i18n-backend` plugin to load the translations. The JSON files with the translations are sitting in the `public/locales` folder. Inside we have +50 folders, each one named with the language code, and inside each one there's a `translation.js` file.

The goal is to decouple this from the main repo since making a small copy change inside a bugfix makes PRs with +60 files and it's annoying for code review. Also allows other teams to make changes to the copy easier without interfering with the UI part.

So my question is, how can I move this to another repo?

Comment: There's no single git command to move files between 2 repositories, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No what I'm asking is, how can I implement this solution? I can't seem to find anything on google